# How to save multiple EditText data with button, and display it on another Activity with floating action button?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have one Edittext in my App, I want to save the Text i wrote in this Edittext by clicking a button and than display it in another activity, but only by clicking a floating action button. And after i click the save button, the Edittext should be blank so i could write something else and again save the new text.

I tried with putextra but i can only pass one Edittext and only display it with one button. By clicking the Floating Button it displays blank Activity, I assume because it is a new Intent so he doesn't passes anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading/writing multiple values from the EditText, you could use SharedPreferences to save these values in your Activity where the EditText is, then read all the values from SharedPreferences in your 2nd Activity. This will let you avoid creating a database for your app as that's a bit of overhead.

Since it's only String data that will be coming from the EditText, I would probably go with a Set - but this won't allow duplicates. You could just store each String under a different key and use the getAll() method instead. Something like below in your onClickListener for your FAB would save the data:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString("UNIQUE_KEY_HERE", "EDIT_TEXT_VALUE_HERE");
editor.commit();
```

And then when reading from SharedPreferences in your 2nd Activity:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String editTextValue = sharedPref.getString("UNIQUE_KEY_HERE", " "); // " " is a default value
```

[There's already plenty of documentation on SharedPreferences anyway](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences), including the `getAll()` method

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, i‘ll try and come back to you if something went wrong

Comment: i got a problem when i save two EditTexts values it overwrites the old one and i got two same values, i have two different keys but it still overwrites the old one.